# Best practice when loading and predicting keras model using flask

Tags: python, google-app-engine, machine-learning, flask, keras

I deployed a small web service (flask) on Google AppEngine with this config `app.yaml`

```
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

I have an endpoint for predicting if a sentence is toxic, unfortunately calling the endpoint is sometimes really slow and sometimes fast.

Of course I only loading the model once and not at each request. When starting flask threaded is False.

```
    list_classes = ["toxic", "severe_toxic", "obscene", "threat", "insult", "identity_hate"]

    with open('tokenizer.pkl', 'rb') as handler:
        tokenizer = pickle.load(handler)

    model = load_model('m.hdf5')

    app = Flask(__name__)

    def prediction(sentence):
        list_tokenized_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([sentence])
        maxlen = 200
        X_t = pad_sequences(list_tokenized_train, maxlen=maxlen)

        pred = model.predict(X_t)[0]

        dic = {}
        for idx, prob  in enumerate(pred):
            dic[list_classes[idx]] = float(prob) 
        return dict(sorted(dic.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1]))


 @app.route('/api/v1/predict/<comment>', methods=['GET'])
 def predict(comment):
     result = prediction(comment)
     return make_response(jsonify({'Comment': comment, 'Result': result}), 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=False)
```

Are there some parts I can enhance for better performance ?

Comment: have you tried logging the time? can you tell that as well?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view your main.py code looks fine, I only can see possible improvements in the app.yaml file.

Choosing manual_scaling and setting the number of instances to 1 may be limiting the response time of your requests. Depending on the number of requests sent to the instance, it may not be able to handle them fast enough. Therefore why there is such a difference between requests.

In order to improve the response time I would suggest you to use [automatic scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#automatic_scaling) instead and also try to make your instance a bit more powerful by giving it more resources in case that automatic scaling does not solve your issue.